# Mysql optimizaiton: is there any way to make this faster?

Tags: mysql, database, join, query-optimization

Update:

Thanks all the help. I will summarize the answers.

From @Jaydee, his answer successfully reduces the result to 0.09seconds, and it is linear to the number in LIMIT.

> select * from (select table1.id as table1_id from table1 where
>   table1.id < 100000 order by table1.id desc limit 1000) t1 inner join
>   table2 on t1.table2_id = table2.id left join table3 on t1.table3_id =
>   table3.id order by t1.id;

From @Rick James, he mentions that it might be problem of Table 2. Because my table 2 only has several columns, I can leave it out, and do the join myself, even at client side!

So I remove table 2, and it is only 0.02s!

> select `table1`.`id` as `table1_id` from `table1` left join `table3`
>   on `table1`.`table3_id` = `table3`.`id` where `table1`.`id` < 100000
>   order by `table1`.`id` desc limit 1000;

At last, I found that, if I change table2 from inner join to left join, then all the pains goes away, it is 0.03s!

> select `table1`.`id` as `table1_id` from `table1` left join `table2`
>   on `table1`.`table2_id` = `table2`.`id` left join `table3` on
>   `table1`.`table3_id` = `table3`.`id` where `table1`.`id` < **100000**
>   order by `table1`.`id` desc limit 1000;

Thanks again for the help!

==============================

Note: I am running on embedded server with limited ram (about 1G, enough to put in all data actually, 200,000 data) and using SD card as storage.

> select table1.id from table1 where id<100000 order by id desc limit
>   1000;

(0.01s)

> select `table1`.`id` as `table1_id` from `table1` inner join `table2`
>   on `table1`.`table2_id` = `table2`.`id` where `table1`.`id` <
>   **100000** order by `table1`.`id` desc limit 1000;

(0.40s)

> select `table1`.`id` as `table1_id` from `table1` inner join `table2`
>   on `table1`.`table2_id` = `table2`.`id` where `table1`.`id` < **1000**
>   order by `table1`.`id` desc limit 1000;

(0.01s)

> select `table1`.`id` as `table1_id` from `table1` inner join `table2`
>   on `table1`.`table2_id` = `table2`.`id` left join `table3` on
>   `table1`.`table3_id` = `table3`.`id` where `table1`.`id` < **100000**
>   order by `table1`.`id` desc limit 1000;

(2.31s)

> select `table1`.`id` as `table1_id` from `table1` inner join `table2`
>   on `table1`.`table2_id` = `table2`.`id` left join `table3` on
>   `table1`.`table3_id` = `table3`.`id` where `table1`.`id` < **1000** order
>   by `table1`.`id` desc limit 1000;

(0.03s)

---

As the comment suggested, I used explain, but I don't really understand what does explain say. Please help me check. The following is the longest 2.31s.

```
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                | type   | possible_keys                                                     | key                                   | key_len | ref                                         | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table2               | index  | PRIMARY,table2_id_index                                           | table1_id_index                       | 4       | NULL                                        |     1 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table1               | ref    | PRIMARY,table1_table2_id_foreign,table1_id_index                  | table1_table2_id_foreign              | 4       | videocap.table2.id                          | 27222 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table3               | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                           | PRIMARY                               | 4       | videocap.table1.table3_id                   |     1 | Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

---

results from desc table

table1:

```
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field                   | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id                      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| table2_id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| table3_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
| created_at              | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at              | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

table2:

```
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| created_at      | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at      | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

table3:

```
+---------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field                     | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+---------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id                        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| created_at                | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at                | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+---------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: what does `explain select` for all the slow queries says ? And are the joining keys indexed ?

Comment: Do you have an index on `table1.id` ?

Comment: table1.id, table2.id, table3.id are primary key. table1.table2_id, table1.table3_id are normal index (mul from desc table1).

Comment: Show the schema with indexes (not hand typed) and output from explain

Comment: Garbage in garbage out you know the drill

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.  We need to see the indexes and engine.  "MUL" is not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like table2 has 1 row.  Is that correct?  How many rows in each table?

With only 1 row in table2, the optimizer seemed to decide to get it out of the way to start with.

In all cases, `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, especially if you are using InnoDB, is optimal for

```
    where     table1.id < $number
    order by  table1.id desc
```

However, if most of the table has id < 100000, then the optimizer may (erroneously) decide to do a table scan (because it did not take into account the `LIMIT`).  What version are you using?  5.6 has some improvements in this area.

Keep in mind that there are millions of variations on queries.  While I appreciate your attempt to isolate the important parts of the query; you may find that applying any answer back to the 'real' query may hit some other hiccup.

Comment: Thanks. Table 1 is currently only 1 row but will have more later (won't be too many), otherwise there's no point for table 2. Acorrding to your clue, I intentially move table 2 out, it is much much faster. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How does this perform? (Ooops. Corrected)

```
select  *
    from  
      ( SELECT  table1.id as table1_id
            from  table1
            where  table1.id < 100000
            order by  table1.id desc
            limit  1000
      ) t1
    inner join  table2 on t1.table2_id = table2.id
    left join   table3 on t1.table3_id = table3.id
    order by  t1.id;
```

Comment: Yes, this reduces to 0.09s, and it is linear to the LIMIT. If I reduce the LIMIT to 100, it will be 0.01s now. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the sub-select minimizes the number of rows that get joined.